# extracting a table values in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

Recently I tried to extract values from the table of a docx and process using python-docx library. During the development stage I found so many errors like index is out of range. Then I build a program just to extract data, the results I cannot understand.

So I made two docx. Example and Example2, which is derived from my original docx. Both are with single table, one has lesser rows and the other has many. This is my code.

```
from docx import Document
doc = Document("C:\\Users\\RAJAGANESH\\Documents\\_Reports_PDF\\Example.docx")
xx = ""
for t1,table in enumerate(doc.tables):
    for r1,row in enumerate(table.rows):
        for c1,cell in enumerate(row.cells):
            xx = xx + f"Tab->{t1}, row->{r1}, col->{c1} = {cell.text}\n"

with open('output.txt','w',encoding='utf-8') as f:
     f.write(xx)
```

by checking the output the example.docx reads 19 cells in a row. whereas example2.docx reads only 11(0-11). Of course, there are only 12 columns in both of tables. I don't know how to process these.

I just want to extract, all the values below Dimensions (Inch) and split into min and max, then check with the values below Observations.

[Example working as expected](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YpBtGmdzABMvRDCiWUUzZD_plox1aSLM/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=104720768073936495290&rtpof=true&sd=true)

[Example2 not working as expected](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1F_eBi_S0UEtp47O8l6wRjXctR6qHNCoY/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=104720768073936495290&rtpof=true&sd=true)